# Return all records if more than 2/3 satisfy a value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table representing multiple transactions by customers in any given day. I need to return all transactions per customer if two thirds or more of the transactions per customer were cash instead of credit card.

In the example below I want to return all of customers' 1, 4 transactions as they were the only customers to have 2 thirds or more of their transactions as cash:

```
+----------------+-------------+-----------------+------------------+
| Transaction ID | CustomerNum | TransactionType | TransactionValue |
+----------------+-------------+-----------------+------------------+
|              1 |           1 | Cash            |               11 |
|              2 |           1 | Card            |               12 |
|              3 |           1 | Cash            |               13 |
|              4 |           2 | Cash            |               14 |
|              5 |           2 | Card            |               15 |
|              6 |           3 | Cash            |               15 |
|              7 |           3 | Card            |               11 |
|              8 |           3 | Cash            |               12 |
|              9 |           3 | Card            |               13 |
|             10 |           4 | Cash            |               14 |
|             11 |           4 | Cash            |               15 |
|             12 |           4 | Cash            |               15 |
+----------------+-------------+-----------------+------------------+
```

Comment: Please post your attempted query (even if it has syntax errors)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to work with the sample data:

```
declare @t table (TranID int not null,CustomerNum int not null,
                  TranType varchar(17) not null,TranValue decimal(18,0) not null)
insert into @t(TranID,CustomerNum,TranType,TranValue) values
( 1,1,'Cash',11),    ( 2,1,'Card',12),    ( 3,1,'Cash',13),
( 4,2,'Cash',14),    ( 5,2,'Card',15),
( 6,3,'Cash',15),    ( 7,3,'Card',11),    ( 8,3,'Cash',12),    ( 9,3,'Card',13),
(10,4,'Cash',14),    (11,4,'Cash',15),    (12,4,'Cash',15)

;With Counted as (
    select *,
        COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerNum) as cnt,
        SUM(CASE WHEN TranType='Cash' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
            OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerNum) as cashcnt
    from @t
)
select * from Counted
where cashcnt * 3 >= cnt * 2
```

I've gone with simple multiplication at the end to keep all of the maths as integers and avoid having to think about float/decimal and the representation of 2/3.

Result:

```
TranID      CustomerNum TranType          TranValue   cnt         cashcnt
----------- ----------- ----------------- ----------- ----------- -----------
1           1           Cash              11          3           2
2           1           Card              12          3           2
3           1           Cash              13          3           2
10          4           Cash              14          3           3
11          4           Cash              15          3           3
12          4           Cash              15          3           3
```

Comment: That is more or less the exact script i was about to post (I used count instead of SUM and removed the ELSE)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select t.*
from (select customernum
      from transactions
      group by customernum
      having sum(case when TransactionType = 'Cash' then 1.0 else 0.0 end) / sum(1.0) > 0.6666) c
join transactions t on t.customernum = c.customernum
```

Comment: when you divide 2 integers in sql, an integer will be returned. So 2/3 = 0. Therefore your answer will not include rows where transaction_id = 1